# Horizontal image list modules to be used wit KO.js and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm evaluating how to implement a UI with Knockout.js and Bootstrap.
Basically, what I want to achieve is a horizontal list of images, (ideally scrollable) where each image also has an information frame.

The list is populated from KO-observableArray.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: thumbnails">
    <span>          
        <a href='#' data-bind='click: select '>
            <img width="120" height="90" data-bind="attr:{ src: image_ref }" />                         
        </a>                        
    </span>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions using an available module, which integrates easily with jQuery, KO, Bootstrap or a hint how this could be implemented manually.

Concerning info-frame within the image, I thought about using jQuery positioning functionality. However as the elements are created by KO dynamically, I have no clue, where to call the jQuery code for placing the elements and how to address the elements.

Thank you for any suggestion!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a plug-in to do this, but it's not too complicated to roll your own layout. This is mostly about CSS. With this HTML:

```
<div class="scrolling-container">
    <div class="image-list" data-bind="foreach:images">
        <div class="image-cell">
            <div class="image-frame">
                <img data-bind="attr:{src:url}" />
                <div class="image-info" data-bind="text:info">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Apply this CSS:

```
.scrolling-container {
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.image-list {
    background-color:#666;
    display:table-row;
}
.image-cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.image-frame {
    position:relative;
}
.image-frame > img {
    vertical-align:top;
    max-height:500px;
}
.image-info {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    opacity:.8;
    background-color:white;
}
```

and season to taste. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z7j1xemx/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! Many CSS keywords, which are new to me. Actually, I'd started bounty in 20 hours for getting the answer.